# How to use mpdecimate with the same codec as the input file and audio on the output file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 60 fps Pro Res Video File where I want to keep every 4th frame (the others are duplicates, so in reality 15 fps). The audio has to remain identical (not shifted by the transformation) in the output file. It seems mpdecimate should do the trick but keeping the identical quality and audio was not easy.

Error with 15 and 20 fps:

```
mov @ 0x7fe9e3003800] Timecode frame rate 20/1 not supported
Output #0, mov, to 'AA.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1280x1024, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 20 fps, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 prores
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> prores (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
```

Comment: If the cadence is regular, you don't need mpdecimate. Just specifying `-r 15` should work.

Comment: Thank you. How exactly would you do this ?

Comment: I get the following error see above

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -r 15 -c:a copy out.mov` Which ffmpeg version do you have?

Comment: v 2.8.4 and the error I get now is: "Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global header". Actually it is the same error and this line is added.

Comment: You can insert `-flags +global_header` to correct that, but you should upgrade to a current version and try.